# Filter out any type of URL in input_get variable, is this the best way?

Tags: php

I've come up with this potential solution but want to double check that there isn't a better/ more efficient way.

If the ?uri contains anything in the $filter array it should exit. Note: I'm wanting to check that it **does not contain a URL** such as ?url=http://google.com, so FILTER_VALIDATE_URL for example wouldn't work.

With my uri, I only want to accept parameters of: 'example', or 'example-example' as the uri is appended onto a variable with a domain already. So an example output would be domain.com/pdf.php?uri=example-example

```
    $uri = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'uri', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $filter = array('http://', 'https://' ,'www.', '.', '@', '/');

    foreach ($filter as $k) {
        if (strpos($uri, $k) === false) {
            // No matches, carry on
        } else {
            // Match is found, exit
            exit("Error in url parameter: $k is not allowed!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a question that belongs over at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as it asks about code quality, not a particular problem.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

As I understand you don't want it to contain any URI schemes or characters such as @ or / or www.

You could use regex to allow only the characters you need:

```
// not valid
$uri = 'http://google.com';

// Is only valid if contains A-Z, a-z, 0-9, -, _
$isValidUri = preg_match('/^[\-A-Za-z0-9_]+$/', $uri);

if ($isValidUri) {
    // Do something here with the valid uri . . .
} else throw new Exception('Not a valid uri');
```

You could also use PHPs [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) or [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) functions to sanitize the input as you have  done. But be **VERY** careful sanitizing user input and make sure to test thoroughly against misuse.

Answer (score 1):

You could define your own custom filter:

```
$uri = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'uri', FILTER_CALLBACK, [
    'options' => function($value) {
        return !preg_match('~https?://|[.@/]~', $value);
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the challenge, PHP usually provides different paths to the same solution. The key is to decide which is best for your particular purpose. Sometimes any code that works is the best solution. Other times, for example, you may need to test a variety of solutions to see which one executes the fastest.

So, you asked if there is a "better or more efficient way". "Better" is subjective; more efficient can be determined by testing. For example, test the code below against your existing code and see which version executes faster.  By doing that, rather than depending on the opinions of others, you will learn how to make your own "which is best" decisions. Doing that will go a long way towards helping you become a better educated programmer.

```
$start = microtime(true);
$myarray = array("http://google.com","ftp://google.com","https://google.com","Nothing to see here");
foreach ($myarray as $uri)
{
if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$uri)) 

{
  echo "$uri contains no matches - carry on<br>";
} else {
          echo "Match is found in $uri, <br>";
       }
}
$elapsed_time = (microtime(true) - $start);
echo "Routine took $elapsed_time seconds to run";
```